# What does "Passe demain" mean?

Tags: traduction, anglais

My manager is at the office some days, while on the other days, she is at the other office location. I wanted to talk to her and so I asked her for the time when can I meet her.

Me: "Bonjour Marie, est-ce que je peux venir te parler demain? S'il vous plaît laissez moi savoir quelle heure vous convient mieux..."

And this is what she replied: "Passe demain je serai là toute la journée".

**I don't understand what "passe demain" means. Does it mean "tomorrow" or "day after tomorrow"?**

Comment: Off topic: 1. You need to decide if you say *tu* or *vous* to Marie. 2. *laisse moi savoir* is an anglicism (let me know), just say *dis-moi* or *dites-moi*.

Comment: @jlliagre "S'il vous plait" in the beginning of the sentence also seems like an anglicism to me ("*Please let me know ...*"). A french would just say "*Dites-moi quelle heure vous convient le mieux*", it's too small of a request to "need" a *s'il vous plaît*.

Comment: *laissez moi savoir* is also something native French speakers wouldn't say. It's a literal translation of let me know. *Dites-moi* is much more natural sounding.

Answer (score 6):

> **Passe demain**, je serai là toute la journée.

Can be translated to "**stop by tomorrow**, I'll be there all day".

The use of *passer* to mean *to stop by* is common, e.g. I'll stop by the supermarket this afternoon -> *je passerai au supermarché cet après-midi*.

Answer (score 0):

en revanche "laisse-moi savoir" (traduction mot à mot de "let me know") est un anglicisme. Je suggèrerais simplement "dis-moi"à la place.